Application of the (simple?) Markov property
I'm trying to understand why does it holds that $$\mathbb{E}_\mu[\mathbb{P}_{X_t}(\tau>s)|\tau>t]=\frac{\mathbb{P}_\mu(\tau>t+s)}{\mathbb{P}_\mu(\tau>t)},$$ where $\mu$ denotes the initial distribution (probability measure) of the Markov process $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $\tau$ is a stopping time.
I'm told, that this is due to the Markov property. I think it refers to the simple markov property:

Let $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\ge0}$ be the canonical filtration for a sequence of random variable $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ on a state space $E$.
Let f be a non-negative measurable function on the sample space $\Omega$ and let $n\ge0$. Then, for every $x\in E$,\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}_x[f\circ\theta_n|\mathcal{F}_n]=\mathbb{E}_{X_n}[f].
\end{equation*}

Intuitively I would justify it saying that the the LHS is equal to the RHS, since, given $\tau>t$, the LHS is equal to the the probability, starting from the initial distribution, of the time $\tau$ when is greater than the sum of both $s$, which was already on the probability on the LHS, and $t$, since in the LHS we were considering the process already at state $t$ ($\mathbb{P}_{X_t}$). Then, why divide by the probability that $\tau>t$?
Probably the last paragraph was just confused, that's why I'm asking for a clarification in understanding this property, maybe also with formulas? Thank you in advance.

On the event $\{\tau >t\}$, you have $\tau=t+\tau\circ\theta_t$. Therefore
$\{\tau>t+s\} =\{\tau>t\}\cap\theta_t^{-1}\{\tau>s\}$. Or, in terms of indicators,
$1_{\{\tau>t+s\}}=1_{\{\tau>t\}}1_{\{\tau>s\}}\circ\theta_t$. Now apply the simple Markov property at time $t$:
$$
\Bbb P_\mu[\tau>t+s]=\Bbb E_\mu[\Bbb E_\mu[1_{\{\tau>s\}}\circ\theta_t\mid\mathcal F_t]1_{\{\tau>t\}}]
=\Bbb E_\mu[\Bbb E_{X_t}[1_{\{\tau>s\}}]1_{\{\tau>t\}}].
$$
Finish by dividing by $\Bbb P_\mu[\tau>t]$.

Thank you for your explanation. Maybe it's not a smart question, but why, when talking in terms of events, we consider the inverse of the shift operator, but in terms of indicator functions, we don't take the inverse anymore?

For a mapping $f:E\to F$ and a set $B\subset F$,
$$f^{-1}B={x\in E: f(x)\in B},
$$
so
$$
1_{f^{-1}B}(x)=1_B(f(x))=1_B\circ f.
$$
